# Can I get a clue as to the meaning of this spam?

Tags: translation

A US forum on home construction has recently been receiving spam such as:

精仿1：1制作原版内布拉斯加大学办理林肯分校UNL毕业证文凭微|Q603012914代办美国成绩单|学位证|伪造假毕业证假学历丨留信网认证+大使馆认证、教育部认证University of Nebraska Lincoln

Can anyone tell me what is being said?  (I apologize if this is not Chinese.)

Comment: What did google translate say?

Comment: If you know it is spam, just ignore it. It is an ads for forged diploma and fake degree. 精仿 means "fine imitation"

Comment: Actually, you should ban the user IP that posted this spam.

Answer (score 3):

high-quality forgeries 1 : 1 (meaning 100% scale; exact copy) production of original University of Nebraska,(issued at) Lincoln branch campus,UNL certificate and diploma|Q603012914 representing US (academic) transcripts|degree diplomas|graduation diplomas, counterfeit record of education |message network authentication + embassy authentication, education department authentication University of Nebraska Lincoln

Comment: 代办美国成绩单 should be "making (forging) US transcript", not "representing"

Comment: absolutely，see e.g. bkrs: 代办[do sth.for sb.] 替人办理